# How to use Math.round?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have function which multiplies 2 numbers and gets answer. I want to round the answer

```js
this.Num = this num1 * this.num2
console.log(this.Num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Num = Math.round(this.num1 * this.num2);
```

Comment: can i use that in ionic

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.

Comment: thank you. it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
Math.round(this.num);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round